# Why rts signal is different if write is done via terminal rather than via application?

Tags: c, shell, serial-port, linux-device-driver

I'm working with an rs232 db9 male connector under Ubuntu 16.04
Let's assume that pin 5 is ground
I can write to the connector from terminal using a command like `echo "pippo" > /dev/ttyS0` and using a protocol analyser I can see that:

- pin 3 is correctly transmitting the signal
- pin 4 and pin 7 are both low before the data transmission
- pin 4 and pin 7 are both high while data transmission on pin 3
- pin 4 and pin 7 are both low after data transmission on pin 3

now if I try to run the following C code

```
int file_descriptor = open ("/dev/ttyS0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
unsigned char* buffer = (unsigned char*)"pippo";
buffer_length = strlen((char*)buffer);
unsigned int written = 0;
while(written<buffer_length){
    unsigned int tmp = write (this_ptr->dev_file_descriptor, buffer+written, buffer_length-written);
    if(tmp <0){
        break;
    }
    written += tmp;
}
tcdrain(this_ptr->dev_file_descriptor);
if(written != buffer_length){
    perror("Serial write failure\n");
    return-1;
}
close(file_descriptor);
```

I can see that

- Data is transmitted on pin 3 BUT
- pin 4 and pin 7 are always LOW

I need RTS and I don't understand why the behaviour is different in these two scenarios.

the output of `stty -F /dev/ttyS0 -a` is actually

> speed 9600 baud; rows 0; columns 0; line = 0;
>   intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = ; eol2 = ; swtch = ; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W;
>   lnext = ^V; discard = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
>   -parenb -parodd -cmspar cs8 hupcl -cstopb cread clocal -crtscts
>   -ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff -iuclc -ixany -imaxbel -iutf8
>   opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
>   isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt echoctl echoke -flusho -extproc

and as I said it works from terminal but it doesn't from my application.

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 1):

Actually following Kevin advice isn't working as setting CRTSCTS makes the application hanging every time that I try to write some bytes to the serial device (I think that the CTS signal is not set by the slave so it keeps waiting for it). I'm going to connect a moxa db9 converter to have an rs485 serial output but for now I'm just checking logical status of the signals with my protocol analyser. 
However the hint is correct, I mean  if I manually set  RTS flag with ioctl function RTS is correctly managed. So if we are interested only in controlling RTS signal without full hardware flow control we must disable CRTSCTS flag with `attr.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS` and then we can make a write function with proper ioctl functions for RTS pin. If instead we have a slave which supports hardware flow control then enabling CRTSCTS flag should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to include all the error handling, I'll leave that as an exercise for the OP.  Please do `man ioctl` / `man tcgetattr` / `man tcsetattr` for all of the correct include files, etc.

You have to set the `CRTSCTS` flag first:

```
struct termios attr, oldterminfo;
int fd, status;

fd = open(devicename, O_RDWR);

tcgetattr(fd, &oldterminfo);
memcpy (&attr, &oldterminfo, sizeof(termios))
attr.c_cflag |= CRTSCTS | CLOCAL;
attr.c_oflag = 0;
tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &attr);
```

Set the `RTS` flag high

```
ioctl(fd, TIOCMGET, &status);
status |= TIOCM_RTS;
ioctl(fd, TIOCMSET, &status);
```

Here is where you'll do your write(s) to the device
.....

And, when complete, set the `RTS` flag low

```
ioctl(fd, TIOCMGET, &status);
status &= ~TIOCM_RTS;
ioctl(fd, TIOCMSET, &status);
```